# If $x$ is a root of the polynomial.....

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove: If $x$ is a root of the polynomial:

[image]

I believe if I assume $\frac{a}{b}$ is a root of the polynomial, where $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, if I plug into the equation above and multiply both sides by $b^m$, and show that $b$ must equal $1$, I can find an answer, but I don't know how to do so.

Comment: Assume $b$ is *not* $1$. After you multiply by $b^m$ count how many of the $m+1$ terms will be multiples of $b$.

Comment: After multiplying by $b^m$, consider some prime $p$ that divides $b$ but not $a$. $p$ divides the right hand side ($0$), so it must divide the left side as well. What goes wrong?

Comment: You'll end up with something like $a^m + b k = 0$ where $k = c_1 a^{m-1} + ... c_m b^{m-1}$ is an integer. Remember that you assumed $a, b$ to be coprime.

Comment: Okay, I think I can sort of see that. How do I use this to construct my answer?

Comment: $b$ can't divide $a^m$ if $a, b$ are relatively prime.

Comment: I feel stupid at this point. i don't get it.

Comment: Try some numerical examples. Does it make sense that $2$ can't divide $a^m$ if $a$ is odd? How about $3$ dividing $5^m$? If that doesn't help, consider the prime factorizations of $a$ and $b$. Since they're coprime, they can't have anything in common.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but what's frustrating me that I don't see how this applies to a solution for the problem, or a step towards one.

Comment: You assume there exists a rational non-integer root $a/b$ with $a, b$ coprime and $b \gt 1$. From there it follows that $a^m + b k = 0$ for some integer $k$ i.e. $b$ divides $a^m$. But that contradicts the assumption of coprimality, so there can't exist any such rational non-integer root, or in other words any rational root must be an integer.

Comment: Is that the solution? It seems like it meets the criteria.

Comment: pleas do not display a picture but use a latex formula in your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments: suppose there's a rational root  $x=a/b$, written in irreducible form, i. e. $a$ and $b$ are coprime, and multiply by $b^m$. You obtain
\begin{align*}
&a^m+c_1a^{m-1}b+c_2a^{m-2}b^2+\dots+c_mb^m=0\\\iff \enspace
&a^m=-b(c_1a^{m-1}+c_2a^{m-2}b+\dots+c_mb^{m-1})
\end{align*}
so $b$ divides $a^m$. As $a$ and $b$, hence $a^m$ and $b$ are coprime, this is impossible, unless $b=\pm1$. This proves $x$ is an integer.

*Note:*  We may likewise prove $a$ is a divisor of $c_m$ if we write the equation as
$$a(a^{m-1}+c_1a^{m-2}b+c_2a^{m-3}b^2+\dots+c_{m-1}b^{m-1})=-c_mb^m.$$